# How much space is remaining on my OneDrive?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, cloud-storage

In regards to unused / available space on my OneDrive. Is there a way to see how much space is remaining / unused on my OneDrive?  In windows file explorer I can right-click my C:\ drive, choose '**Properties'** then I can see '**Used Space**' and '**Free Space**' and some other info. **Is there a way to see this same type of detail on my OneDrive?**

Comment: Just go to OneDrive, your storage space, is at the bottom of the website.

Comment: Wow that's terrific information! Odd how it wasn't mentioned anywhere in all of the my searches over the past couple of weeks and it's so simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Can be done via OneDrive web app > Options > Manage storage

https://onedrive.live.com or by right clicking on the OneDrive taskbar icon > Manage storage

This will show a bar graph of used/unused as well as the largest files on your OneDrive

Answer (score 1):

Go here: https://onedrive.live.com and chek the left lower corner.

Or use right click- propertiles on you PC where your one drive folder is located.

---

[Check-one-drive-space-used-by-going-to-onedrive.live.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FsPA.png)